# SQL: Average kids per father

Tags: sql, average

I have to create a sql statement which shows the fathers and their average number of kids.

This is my sql script:

```
create table breeder (
breederNumber   number(3) primary key,
name            varchar2(20),
residence       varchar2(20),
password        varchar2(20)
);

create table race (
raceCode        varchar2(2) primary key,
raceName        varchar2(20) not null
);

create table sheep (
earTagNumber    number(2) primary key,
father          number(2),
mother          number(2),
raceCode        varchar2(2),
name            varchar2(20),
previousBreeder number(3),
genotype        varchar2(7),
gender          varchar2(1) check (gender = 'M' OR gender = 'F'),

constraint fk_previousBreeder foreign key (previousBreeder) references breeder(breederNummer) on delete cascade,
constraint rk_raceCode foreign key (raceCode) references race(raceCode) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_mother foreign key (mother) references sheep(earTagNumber) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_father foreign key (father) references sheep(earTagNumber) on delete cascade
);
```

This is what I have so far:

```
select (s1.father), avg(s2.earTagNumber) as averageNumberOfKids
from sheep s1
join sheep s2 on s1.earTagNumber= s2.father
group by s1.father;
```

Output what I got:

```
FATHER AVERAGENUMBEROFKIDS
------ -------------------
                      6.75
```

Can anyone help me?

Some test data: http://pastie.org/5452411

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to create the sql query?  If so please show the query you've written so we can see where you've had problems.  You shouldn't just be asking people for code...

Comment: Show us what you've done already.  Hint for getting started: you don't even have a `select` in your example.  Also, check your textbook for "Aggregate Functions"

Comment: I added it in the first post

Comment: @arbn: the homework tag has been [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's total number of kids per father:

```
Select 
  fathers.EarTagNumber,
  fathers.Name,
  Count(*) As NumberOfKids
From
  sheep fathers
    Inner Join 
  sheep children
    On fathers.earTagNumber = children.father
Group By
  fathers.EarTagNumber,
  fathers.Name;
```

Here's average number of kids (total kids / number of fathers)

```
Select
  Avg(NumberOfKids) As AvgKids
From (
  Select 
    fathers.EarTagNumber,
    Count(*) As NumberOfKids
  From
    sheep fathers
      Inner Join 
    sheep children
      On fathers.earTagNumber = children.father
  Group By
    fathers.EarTagNumber
) a;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5121/10